# Are there any "inter-record" functions in R's data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table:

```
AssetNumber StartDate   ActionNumber    PerviousActionNumber
1       20090602    1   
1       20090626    3           
1       20090721    5           
1       20091008    1           
2       20090604    3           
2       20090628    2           
2       20090723    1           
2       20091010    2           
2       20091018    3
```

Load the dataset with:

```
set <- structure(list(AssetNumber = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    StartDate = c(20090602L, 20090626L, 20090721L, 20091008L, 
    20090604L, 20090628L, 20090723L, 20091010L, 20091018L), ActionNumber = c(1L, 
    3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), PerviousAction. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("AssetNumber", "StartDate", 
"ActionNumber", "PerviousActionNumber"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I am seeking to add the "ActionNumber" from the previous record in the column "PreviousActionNumber". Does anybody can advise me on what function to use to accomplish this? I expect to get the following result:

```
AssetNumber StartDate   ActionNumber    PerviousActionNumber
1           20090602            1   
1           20090626            3           1
1           20090721            5           3
1           20091008            1           5
2           20090604            3           1
2           20090628            2           3
2           20090723            1           2
2           20091010            2           1
2           20091018            3           2
```

More in general, is there a specific package in R that includes inter-record functions like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for an assignment by reference using `:=`. This is pretty basic. I suggest you read the `data.table` manual/documentation.

```
# thanks to @agstudy
dt[, previousActionNumber := c(NA, head(ActionNumber, -1))]
```